# Shopware 6 Administration: filtered list ignores variants

Tags: shopware6

The manufacturer filter in the default product list (parent) ignores variants that contain the searched manufacturer. The list remains empty if the parent product has no manufacturer.

An empty list indicates that there are no products at all from a particular manufacturer. This behavior is not very intuitive.

Is there a default configuration to show specific products and variants of a product at a specific manufacturer?

Comment: Are you talking about the frontend or the admin panel? Can you be more specific? It's not yet clear for me what you are asking.

Comment: @Alex as the title says: administration